# Extensionless URLs with OmniFaces FacesView does not work in 1.12

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, web.xml, tomcat8, omnifaces

i am already using the nice omnifaces-lib (1.12) with some of its util-functions successfully. now i want to try its facesviews-feature for extensionless urls. after reading

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs

and adding the magic line

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
  <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

to web.xml, it does not to seem have any effect. the server-console also does not tell anything about the new  configuration.

calling http://localhost:8080/TestApp/test results in "requested resource is not available" while http://localhost:8080/TestApp/test.jsf works as expected. i also tried the examples from

http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.2/org/omnifaces/facesviews/package-summary.html

is there any (configuration)-issue? thanks for any advice.

i am using mojarra 2.2.8 and omnifaces 1.12 and tomcat 8. i don't have any other jsf-libs such as primefaces or prettyfaces included.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Test</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
    <!-- param-value>Production</param-value -->
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>


</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was my mistake. The `/META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file disappeared during the 1.10 split. That file contained an instruction to let the container execute the `org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsInitializer` class during startup, which in turn is responsible for scanning and registering extensionless files. It works fine in all 2.x versions and the last 1.x version where it worked is 1.8.3.

It has been added back in [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/9d834a64efdef913eb3ab09409ab6a62de7f4f9f) and a new 1.12.1 release has been baked. It's available [here](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/1.12.1/) in Maven.

Comment: @BalusC hey, extensionless responds with a 301 status code for example for links that are added through javascript and for which the extension wasn't removed. I don't know if that is intended or not and I wanted to let you know. I had to change some js today in order to make things work as before using extensionless.